# Handling overflows in flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am trying to create a layout as below:
[image]

This is the code I have to generate the layout:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 30px;
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
}

#sec1,
#sec3 {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#sec2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <section id="sec1">Section1</section>
  <section id="sec2">
    <div class="panel">
      Panel
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="sec3">Section3</section>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

The problem is that when the screensize reduces, I want the scroll bars to appear in section 2, so that I can scroll and look at the panel. Currently the scroll does not happen at all and only the vertical scroll bar appears. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex items shrink by default; since `flex-direction` is implicitly `row`, they will shrink their width.

Also, you are setting both `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`, which means half of both of its dimension will be cut. As the vertical and horizontal scrollbars start at the top and left, accordingly, you can only scroll to the bottom and the right part of `.panel`.

Explanation in non-ASCII art:

```
justify-content: center
   ◄───────│──────►
   ┌────.panel────┐ ▲
   │              │ │
   │   ┌#sec2─╖   │ │
   │   │      ║   │ │
   │   │      ║   │─── align-items: center
   │   │      ║   │ │
   │   ╘══════╝   │ │
   │              │ │
   └──────────────┘ ▼
```

To prevent this, add `flex-shrink: 0` and use `margin: auto`:

```css
.panel {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.panel {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Demo only */

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 30px;
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
}

#sec1,
#sec3 {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#sec2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <section id="sec1">Section1</section>
  <section id="sec2">
    <div class="panel">
      Panel
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="sec3">Section3</section>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: The diagram seems to be swapped. .panel should be inside #sec2. But the ASCII art suggests otherwise. Can you let me know if the art and the code are in sync?

Comment: @codingsplash That is exactly what happens when `.panel` overflows `#sec2` if you use `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`. My code prevents that entirely so they demonstrate two different cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Because, by default flex item are able to shrink. so there with of 700px won't apply exactly in section two.
> Use `flex-shrink:0` to avoid this.

[DOC HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 30px;
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
}

#sec1,
#sec3 {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#sec2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: grey;
  flex-shrink:0 /* add this */
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <section id="sec1">Section1</section>
  <section id="sec2">
    <div class="panel">
      Panel
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="sec3">Section3</section>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```